Kerberos authentication in IIS

I have 2 VMS. VM1 is a Windows AD Server with IIS installed and VM2 is a Windows 11 VM. Both VMs are joined on a domain.
I can access the default IIS webpage both on VM1 using localhost and on VM2 using http://<FQDN-of-VM1>.
I have disabled "Anonymous" authentication on IIS and only have "Windows Authentication" enabled.
Under "Windows Authentication" I have made sure "Negotiate " is above "NTLM"
I have verified that I have HOST/<hostname-of-VM1> and HOST/<FQDN-of-VM1> as SPNS
I have verified that I can do telnet <IP-address-of-VM1> 88 from VM2

When I try to access http://<FQDN-of-VM1> it apprears that I am using NTLM and not Kerberos. I am verifying this by executing klist on VM2 and I am not seeing a ticket.
Would someone be able to help me out? Is my configuration incorrect? Are my SPNs incorrect or could I be missing something else?

IIS on domain controller isn't a typical setup, so you'd better try a 3-machine environment. Besides, learn how to troubleshoot Kereberos connections, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/kerberos-authentication-troubleshooting-guidance

Are you not seeing any tickets in klist, or are you not seeing the 'HTTP/fqdn' ticket only? (If I remember correctly, 'HTTP' is part of default sPNMappings so it doesn't need to be registered separately on the AD side... but it's what would show up on the client side.)
